# Come introduco una interrogativa indiretta che gioca il ruolo di complemento di termine?

Tags: interrogatives

Se la forma diretta è

> Alla domanda "Quale giocattolo è verde?", la risposta sarebbe "La macchinina"

qual è la forma indiretta?

La seguente è corretta? Se no, come dovrei esprimermi?

> - Alla domanda su quale giocattolo sia/è verde, la risposta sarebbe [che è] la macchinina

Comment: Puoi specificare cosa immagini al posto di xyz? Siccome è la parte che di solito è modificata per formare la forma indiretta, in un certo senso è la parte più rilevante per la risposta.

Comment: Grazie per l'edit, ma continuo a non capire - la risposta nell'esempio non è una risposta alla domanda.

Comment: @DenisNardin, _xyz_ è il **_nome_** o comunque un identificativo di uno degli oggetti tra i quali la domanda chiede di scegliere.

Comment: Un ultima domanda - dov'è il complemento di termine nell'esempio? Non vedo nessun elemento della frase che svolga questo ruolo.

Comment: _La risposta **alla domanda x** è y_. Forse non è complemento di termine? :(

Comment: Occhio: “qual è”, non *“qual'è”.

Comment: @DenisNardin: In effetti la situazione è un po' dubbia (come spesso succede volendo far rientrare la lingua nel casellario dei complementi). _Potrebbe_ essere un complemento di termine se lo consideriamo come una forma derivata da “dare una risposta a una domanda” (anche se non la “diamo” nello stesso senso in cui possiamo dare una mela a Gino).

Comment: Secondo me la frase in forma indiretta è corretta, ma risulta un po' faticosa, è uno stle un po' da 'esercizio di grammatica'. Scriverei forse: 'La risposta alla domanda su quale giocattolo è verde sarebbe 'la macchinina''. più fluido.  Però tutto dipende dal contesto e da quello che si vuole esprimere, e dallo stile desiderato, quindi va bene comunque. E poi anche la forma diretta è un po' faticosa.